# es6 call class methods within class but also within a on click function

Tags: ecmascript-6

I have this es6 class:

```
class CommentsController {
  constructor() {
    this.$addCommentForm = $('.add-comment')
    this.$addCommentButton = $('.add-comment input[type=submit]')
  }

  init() {
    this.addCommentFormListener();
  }

  addCommentFormListener() {
    this.$addCommentButton.on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      let imageId = parseInt($(this).parents('ul').data('id'));
      let inputText = $(this).parents('ul').find('.user-text').val();
      let comment = new Comment(inputText, imageId);
      debugger;
      CommentsController.renderComment(comment, imageId)
    });
  }

  renderComment(comment, imageId) {
    let image = Image.all[imageId]
    image.comments.push(comment)
    $('#images').find(`ul[data-id=${imageId}] ul#comments-${imageId}`).append(`<li>${comment.text}</li>\n`);
  }
}
```

The problem is that at the debugger, I want to call the renderComment function but I cannot because `this` does not refer to the controller anymore. What can I do?

Comment: Of course, `renderComment` doesn't use `this` at all, so it doesn't really matter. You could just make it a `static` method (that's how you are calling it anyway - on the `CommentsController` class, not an instance) and it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead of a function:

> An arrow function does not have its own this; the this value of the
>   enclosing execution context is used.

However, now you can get the clicked element from `this`, because `this` refers to the instance. Instead get the clicked element using [Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target):

```
  addCommentFormListener() {
    this.$addCommentButton.on('click', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      const $el = $(e.target);
      const imageId = parseInt($el.parents('ul').data('id'));
      constinputText = $el.parents('ul').find('.user-text').val();
      const comment = new Comment(inputText, imageId);

      this.renderComment(comment, imageId)
    });
  }
```